# BufferedReader not taking input even after pressing enter

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

```
public static void main (String Args[]) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String s = br.readLine();
    s=s+" ";
    s.toLowerCase();
    String word="";
    String max="";
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        while(ch!=' ')
            word+=ch;

        if(word.length()>max.length()){
            max=word; count++;
        }
        else count++;
    }System.out.println(max+" , "+count);
}
}
```

I want to find the biggest word in the string without using split or anything like that and also count how many words are present in the sentence.
When I input anything and press enter nothing happens. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problem with reading input from console.

```
while(ch!=' ')
    word+=ch;
```

It makes a infinite loop. you should update this `while-loop` like -

```
while(ch!=' '){
   word+=ch;
   ch = s.charAt(++i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a lame mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in there

```
 while(ch!=' ')
            word+=ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, it works, no error in the readLine.

But I see an infinite loop at:

```
while(ch!=' ')
        word+=ch;
```

Please check the logic once...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LengthiestWord {

    public static void main (String Args[]) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter String");
        String s = br.readLine();
        s=s+" ";
        s.toLowerCase();
        String word="";
        String max="";
        int count=0;

        for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            while(ch!=' '){
                 word+=ch;
                 ch = s.charAt(++i);
           }

            if(word.length()>max.length()){
                max=word;
                word="";
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count++;
                word="";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max+" , "+count);
    }
}
```

O/P ---->>>>

Enter String

all errors are fixed

errors , 4